# Jitsi conversation history location

Tags: jitsi

I am customizing Jitsi and I just want to ask if Jitsi stores conversation locally 
or on server ?

If it stores locally than what is its location ? I have searched a lot but I am helpless. Please Help !

Comment: Did you find the solution @Darshit?

Comment: Not yet ... At that time I tried a lot but I didn't find location. I had analysed code but helpless.

Comment: anything new here @Darshit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Jitsi, the Java XMPP client, then your message history should be stored locally in an XML file if you haven't disabled the logging. The exact location depends on your OS. I would assume the default Java application storage locations like

- Windows: %AppData%\Jitsi\history_ver1.0\messages
- Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/Jitsi/history_ver1.0/messages
- Linux: ~/.jitsi/history_ver1.0/messages

You can add a log statement to see the document that is being written and specifically to which file in the [HistoryImpl source](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi/blob/master/src/net/java/sip/communicator/impl/history/HistoryImpl.java#L263).

If you are using Jitsi-Meet, the browser based client, then your message history is not stored permanently by default as far as I know.

No matter which client you are using, on the server, your messages may or may not be stored. The following assumes you are connecting to an XMPP server. If you are using a XMPP server that chooses to store your messages through the XEP [Message Archive Management](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html), it will be stored. In that case it will be in the storage backend of the XMPP server, most likely a SQLite/MySQL/Postgres database. If you've used the Debian quick install, by default, Jitsi-Meet installs the XMPP server, Prosody, and routes all your chats there. Prosody supports MAM but it isn't on by default as of version 0.9 (it requires version 0.10+ according to their [xeplist](http://prosody.im/doc/xeplist)).

Note network architecture looks like follows. At any point if you are logging messages, then you could potentially find/reconstruct your message history.

```
          Client (Jitsi or Jitsi-Meet browser frontend)
                   |                           |
                   |                           |
                   v                           |
                  443                          |
               +-------+                       |
               |       |                       |
               | NginX |                       |
               |       |                       |
               +--+-+--+                       |
                  | |                          |
+------------+    | |    +--------------+      |
|            |    | |    |              |      |
| jitsi-meet +<---+ +--->+ prosody/xmpp |      |
|            |files 5280 |              |      |
+------------+           +--------------+      v
                     5222,5347^    ^5347      4443
                +--------+    |    |    +-------------+
                |        |    |    |    |             |
                | jicofo +----^    ^----+ videobridge |
                |        |              |             |
                +--------+              +-------------+
```

Diagram taken and slightly modified from the [manual-install.md file in jitsi-meet's repo.](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/b8189a31adc2cb3351402799f694a2ebe809fcaf/doc/manual-install.md#network-description)

Comment: How can we implement Prosody 0.10+ for Jitsi Meet?